# Sharepoint and Active Directory

Tags: windows, sharepoint, server

I would like to create a server infrastructure for SharePoint Server 2013. We would like to buy 2 servers, which the first one will be a domain controller and on the second there will be a SharePoint Server. Now I am thinking about Windows Server version to buy. I would like to buy Windows Server 2012 Standard R2, which will be installed on a domain controller server. On the SharePoint server I am planning to install Windows Server 2012 Essentials R2.

We will have about 100 CAL licences on AD.

The question is if it will work with Essentials server.

Thank you for you answers.

Comment: Interesting, I suggest you to join this other community too! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the Microsoft SharePoint Requirements page -> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx

In general it will work. The problem is the CAL number. With Essentials you can only have a max number of 75 CALs.

Here is also a good article about that topic: http://www.sbsfaq.com/?p=3617

> This new Windows Server 2012 Essentials however is different again – it’s designed with a limit of 25 users.  After that you need to
>   break it out into the normal Windows Server products with the normal
>   Windows Server CALs.

Comment: Thanks, I read that most times but finally now I caught the answer :-))

Comment: Did it. There is some waiting time for doing that

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post and extended it with some additional information.